# Show user's total comment count outside The Loop in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, count, comments

How do I display a user's total comment count outside The Loop?

I use this code to display comment count **inside the loop**:

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $post->post_author;
    $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;
    $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total
    FROM {$wpdb->comments}
    {$where}
");
    echo 'Comments: <strong>' . $comment_count . '</strong>';
    ?>
```

That works fine inside the loop. In an attempt to make that code work outside the loop, I changed `$user_id = $post->post_author;` to `$user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );` but it did not work.

The closest that I have been is with this code:

```
                            <?php
                            global $wpdb;
                            $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
                            $comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
                                SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
                                FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                                {$where}
                                GROUP BY user_id
                                ", object);
                            foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
                                $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
                                echo 'Comments: ' . $count->total . '
                                ';
                            }
                            ?>
```

However, this echos comment count for all users, like this: "Comments: 28 Comments: 11 Comments: 55" etc

What code can I use to **show the user's comment count outside the loop**?

Comment: You will need to make `$post` global if you are using it outside the post.. `global $wpdb, $post;`

Comment: I changed **global $wpdb;** to **global $wpdb, $post;** in my first code and changed **$user_id = $post->post_author;** to **$user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );** but it did not work. Did I do anything wrong according to your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making a few things more global and getting the user data differently.

```
<?php

global $wpdb, $post, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$userId = $current_user->ID;

$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $userId ;
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total 
                                 FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                                 {$where}");
echo 'Comments: <strong>' . $comment_count . '</strong>';
?>
```

or in functions.php

```
<?
function commentCount() {
    global $wpdb, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $userId = $current_user->ID;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var('
             SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) 
             FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' 
             WHERE user_id = "' . $userId . '"');
    echo $count . ' comments';
}
?>
```

To call it

```
  <?php commentCount(); ?>
```

Comment: This code worked but it gave me an error. On the page that I use it, which is in the wp-admin backend (for a plugin), it showed this error:  **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**. I checked that line and it contains: **foreach ($post as $post) {** Is there anyway to alter your code so that it does not conflict with this?

Comment: I just removed $post from Global and everything works without the error too. Do you know why it works without the $post? I am just curious so that I understand what this is doing before I use it on my live site.

Comment: I should note that this is an excellent answer, which is why I have upvoted it and accepted it. Cheers brother.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it works for you. If it doesn't, with some more information I could provide something better. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is old but just want to drop a snippet, which is far more suitable :

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_id' => 1, // use post_id, not post_ID
        'count' => true //return only the count
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
echo $comments

?>
```

Where 'post_id' can be 'user_id'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() . '"` to get the comment per user if you are watching their profile... The code of @SMacFadyen will give the logged in users comment count only.

Besides, the second function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$post= get_post($id=5);
$comment_count = $post->comment_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = get_comments(array(
    'user_id'   => 1,
    'count'     => true, // return comment count instead of comments
));

echo $count;
```

Answer (score -1):

As a function, passing the $user_id - also uses $wpdb->prepare() method to format the query:

```
function get_comment_count( $user_id = null ) {

    if ( is_null( $user_id ) ) { return 0; }

    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
            SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total 
            FROM {$wpdb->comments}
            WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = '%d'
        ",
        (int) $user_id
    ));

}
```